Postman rest calls are not working in windows 11 to vs code
I was writing some code in Spring Boot using VS Code. Just for testing purpose to make sure everything is working fine, I was testing REST API Calls to my controller class using POSTMAN and browser. While making call to my testing method in my controller class, it gives status code "404 Not Found". The code runs on port number 8080, my REST URL is "http://localhost:8080/tulip/testing" type=GET. Earlier I was also getting error for React project, where vs code was unable to run npx command. and the issue was with the windows defender antivirus as it was blocking the connection. but now I also have added vs code as exclusion but still it is not working. The vs code issue is also there in my company laptop, but there Spring Tool Suite works fine and Postman is able to make calls there. Any solution for this?
output in POSTMAN
{
    "timestamp": "2024-05-05T17:08:33.502+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/tulip/testing"
}

Main class
package com.ekart.tulip;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TulipApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TulipApplication.class, args);
    }

}


Controller class
package com.ekart.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ekart.dto.UserDTO;
import com.ekart.service.TulipService;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tulip")
public class TulipController {

    @Autowired
    TulipService tulipService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TulipController.class);

    @GetMapping("/testing")
    public String testing() {
        return "testing";
    }
    

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> register(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
        logger.info("*************register method invoked*****************");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(tulipService.register(userDTO));
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(null);
    }
    
    
}

I am expecting Postman to be able to make REST API calls to my Spring Boot project in VS Code.

Hard to help you as is. One solution for you could be to use debugger mode in Spring and look at the URI discovered/available in the Http Servlet context

postman is just a client. It is your Java application that is likely behaving differently.

It might sound silly, but try rebuild your project again. I tried to reproduce the problem based on the provided information, and the only thing that can produce the problem is that the @GetMapping added or changed but changed has not applied to the build.

Thanks, I tried, but it did not work., I think main culprit here is the windows itself but not sure about the exactly where is the problem.

Try adding the following to your InventoryApp class
@SpringBootApplication @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = <ControllerClassName>.class) public class <main class>{ ... 
spring-boot will scan for components in packages below com.nice.application, so if your controller is in com.nice.controller you need to scan for it explicitly.  ** this worked for me **
